# Grabbing Links from Custom Task-pane in Outlook

Tags: outlook, vsto, office365, office-addins, office-2016

My current setup I have a custom task-pane that shows an iframe of the Wikipedia Website. My next goal is when I click on a item/picture or anything that has a html link to grab that link and put it in the body of the email. Currently when I click on a link from the task-pane it launches a separate instance of my web browser to view that link. I've tried listening for click events but no luck. Is there a way to prevent a web browser from launching when I click on links and just grab the link and put it in the body? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using an iframe: with your current design, you have no control over the content from Wikipedia. Instead, use Wikipedia APIs to generate the desired content on your own page, and modify the `href` attribute on all the links to trigger your custom function instead.

Microsoft has published a complete code sample on GitHub for a working Wikipedia add-in developed in this manner: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Apps/tree/master/Wikipedia

Comment: Hmmm makes sense, but what if it's not Wikipedia but just a random website that contains links and such?

Comment: Well you'll still need to use APIs. Or if they're not available you can always resort to web-scraping. Just check the terms of use for any site before you use their content in your add-in.